# MATLAB - lsim() function not giving proper attenuation for my RC transfer function

Tags: matlab, filtering, transfer-function

I am trying to model a RC filter's transfer function in order to know how an input signal is deformed when it reaches my sample.  I first build the RC filter's transfer function to fit my experimental data but when I give an input signal to the lsim() function, it doesn't give me proper results, even for a sine.

Here's my piece of code:

```
R = 1000000; L = 1; C = 2.5*10^(-12);
G=tf([1], [R*C, 1]);
figure(1)
h=bodeplot(G,'b.-', opts);

f=10^(5);%signal frequency, Hz
tau=1/f;%Signal period, s
Tf=10*tau;%Signal duration
N=100000;%number of samples per period
Ts=tau/N;%Sampling time
figure(2);
[input_vector,t_vector]=gensig('sin',tau,Tf,Ts);
lsim(G,input_vector,t_vector);
```

For a sine at 100kHz, I should be getting -0.25dB of attenuation, therefore about 2% on voltage.  Here it gets me a result 45% lower than my input signal.

Answer (score 0):

It must be your intuition about some detail. I get exactly the proper results expected by running your code.

[image]

Comment: When i plot the bodeplot(), it gives me the attenuation in dB, not the magnitude like this...  and for the values of R and C I am giving, it gives me 0.25 dB attenuation at 1kHz.  

What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: @Exeko you can right click and change the units. matlab 2017a

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from the conversion from rad/s to Hz, which introduces a 2*pi factor, shifting the attenuation curve to the left.